# How do I get data out of a trailing closure that uses session.datatask(with: request)?

Tags: ios

I have a fetchJson function that uses session.datatask to fetch a simple JSON object (string) from OpenWeatherMap server. The question is when I invoke this function using a trailing closure I can print the json object in the trailing closure but when I try to print the jsonobject outside of the trailing closure it prints nil.Is there any way I can print this jsonobject outside the closure.?Basically I need to access the json object outside the trailing closure.Here is my fetchjson code:

```
func fetchJson(completion: @escaping (Any)->Void){
let Url = composeURL(cityname: "Boston")
let request = URLRequest(url:Url)

let task = session.dataTask(with: request) {
    (data, response, error) ->Void in
    if let jsonData = data {
        do{
            let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])

            OperationQueue.main.addOperation

                {completion(jsonObject)
            }
        } catch let error {
            print ("error creating JSON Object: \(error)")
        }

    }else if let requestError = error{
        print("error fetching weather json string: \(requestError)")
    }else {
        print("Unexpected error with reuqest")
    }

}//end of task
task.resume()

}//end of fecth json
```

Here is my call to fetchJson in my view controller:

```
var Jacks : Any!

fetchJson(){
   json in


    Jacks = json
    print(Jacks)///This prints the jsonobject correctly


   }

    print(Jacks) //This prints the jsonobject as nil
```

I don't understand why Jacks would be nil after I assigned it the jsonobject.Any Ideas?How Do I retrieve the jsonobject outside of the trailing closure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is because your `fetchJson()` function is asynchronous. The code inside your closure is called only when your data has been fetched successfully, however the print statement on the last line is run immediately after calling `fetchJson()`. At this point, your `Jacks` object is still nil.

If your app needs to update its UI or perform additional any additional logic after fetching the JSON data, I recommend moving that logic into a separate function that you call inside the closure. As an example:

```
func updateView(with jacks: Jacks) {
    // additional logic here
}
```

Comment: So basically what you are saying is that there is no way I can print Jacks outside the closure or even reference it?

Comment: @Minty You can, but you can only do it _after_ you've got a result from your API call. Do you mind sharing what kind of logic you're trying to perform?

Comment: Basically I just need the Jacks variable with the json data accessible outside of the closure to use in different parts of my view controller. Jacks is actually a global variable in my view controller. How do I get the json data assigned to Jacks and used outside the trailing closure?

Comment: @Minty have a look at this example project I made: [DogApi](https://github.com/adamhaafiz/DogApi). Line 26 in the ViewController.swift file is what you are looking for. After assigning the data to dogsJson (line 25), we can use it in other parts of the application (line 52).